# Is there any difference between Unified Build Agent vs Unified Test Agent?

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, azure-pipelines, agent

I am a newbie to TFS Build Pipeline. Is there any difference between Unified Build Agent vs Unified Test Agents in TFS 2018 Context?

What are Unified Agents and how they help to minimize effort and Build machines pool? Any Step by Step Guide.

*PS:* I have setup simple build definition and it is compiling the code. For testing, the build output gets a copy on multiple dedicated machines where the test runs.
I was doing some R & D and found that there is a concept Unified Agent where you are not required to copy Build output to multiple dedicated machines and run tests there.
Unified Agents do this itself without copying build output and run tests without dedicating machines. You just need to mention VMs (Test Machines) in a Machines Pool where it automatically pics it up.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have confusion about `Visual Studio Test` task. With this task, you can run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, etc. can also be run. **In version 2.* of `Visual Studio Test` task, tests can be distributed on multiple agents**.

> **What's new in version 2.***
>
> - **Run tests using agent phase**: Unified agent across Build, Release and Test allows for automation agents to be used for testing
>     purposes    as well. You can distribute tests using the multi-agent
>     phase    setting. Multi-config phase setting can be used to replicate
>     tests in    different configurations. Check this blog for more information: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/03/26/vstest-task-dons-a-new-avatar-testing-with-unified-agents-and-phases/
> - **Test Impact Analysis**: Automatically select and run only the tests needed to validate the code change.
> - Use the **Visual Studio Test Platform Installer** task to run tests    without needing a full Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I have created an agent pool with 4 Machines on which Agent is installed. I want to use those 4 machines like : 1) My build gets compiled on these agents. 2) All unit test and long running finctional test get run on these machines where i dont need to install anything and limit machine names. This is what i want to achieve.

Comment: You just need to select an agent queue in your build definition, then it will pick a build agent to queue the build automatically. Make sure the capability the  build need has been installed on your build agent machine. Get more information of build agent here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts.